# How do I schedule a task at a random time via VBscript file?

Tags: random, vbscript, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to write a VBscript that will schedule a task to start at a random time.

When I double click the VBscript it gets executed without any errors, but the task scheduler doesn't get updated with the new task.

```
sRndTime = Random2DigitNumber(08, 17) & ":" & Random2DigitNumber(0, 59) & ":" & Random2DigitNumber(0, 59)

Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "SchTasks /create /tn New_Test_Task /sc WEEKLY /D MON,TUE /st " & sRndTime & " /TR ""C:\main_command.vbs"" /ru ""SYSTEM""", 1, True

Function Random2DigitNumber(iLower, iUpper)
Randomize
Random2DigitNumber = Right("00" & Int((iUpper - iLower + 1) * Rnd + iLower), 2)
End Function
```

I cannot see where is the issue with this code.

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to read the returning value `MsgBox CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("schtasks /create ...", 0, True)` (0 - success, -2147467259 - failed).

Comment: Hey omegastripes, thanks! I am getting the message "2147467259" when I run it.

Comment: First of all you have to get to work the `SchTasks` command. Open console (run `cmd.exe`), type the command that are being executed within the script and check the result, error description, etc. Please add any details to the question, don't post them in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Prepend `cmd /k` to the command. If you aren't running as admin you will see Access Denied. It works apart from that.

But it's madness. You are a program not a user. Do things programs' way.

```
Set TS = CreateObject("Schedule.Service")
TS.Connect("ComputerName")

Set rootFolder = TS.GetFolder("\")

Set tasks = rootFolder.GetTasks(0)

If tasks.Count = 0 Then 
    Wscript.Echo "No tasks are registered."
Else
    WScript.Echo "Number of tasks registered: " & tasks.Count

    For Each Task In Tasks
    A=Task.Name
    A = A & " " & Task.NextRunTime
    wscript.echo A
    Next
End If
```

Comment: Thank you Noodles for the help, however I don't see how this answer applies to my question. When executed, your answer lists all of the tasks in the task scheduler, but it doesn't create any tasks with random trigger time. Could you edit your code so that it creates the task at random time?

Comment: The point of my answer is to show you the object you need (Schedule.Service). Then you search the Technical Reference. It shows you use `RegisterTaskDefinition` to create one. Look here for sample code. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383665(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thank you for the link. I think I'll be able to assemble the code following the sample code from microsoft's documentation.